# #Ubuntu: touchpad dies after return from sleep, reactivates after mouse plugged in and out

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

My laptop runs Ubuntu 19.10.

Once I reopen my laptop, my touchpad buttons don't work anymore. However, I can still move around the curser, but I can't click anything anymore (left and right button, no touchpad clicks).

The behavior turns back to normal once I plug a mouse in and out, but I need a mouse for that fix.

What is a way to fix this permanently? Which log could tell me more about it?

Comment: On Windows, It's a driver issue and frequently occurs with Synaptics touchpads; however, if it's only occurring while an external mouse is plugged in when resuming from sleep, there may be setting in Ubuntu's mouse settings page.

Comment: @JW0914: You misunderstand: it occurs regardless of whether a mouse is attached. But plugging a mouse in and out seems to reactivate the touchpad.

Comment: dmesg and journalctl may provide some hints about the hardware issue.